# Iconos firma digital fallan

Tags: html, css, imagen, firma-digital

Estoy intentando realizar una firma digital para una empresa pero estoy teniendo problemas con los social icons ya que no se me estan acomodando horizontalmente debajo del logo sino verticalmente y ademas tienen mucho margen entre estos mismos. si alguein conoce la manera de solucionarlo lo agradeceria mucho.
deberia quedar asi: [image: Foto como deberia quedar]

pero me queda asi: [image: Error]

Adjunto codigo:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Create two equal columns that floats next to each other */

.column1 {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.column2 {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100px;
  /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
}

.column3 {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  font-size: xx-small;
  font-family: Poppins;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100px;
  /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
}

.column4 {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
}

.column5 {
  float: left;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
}

.prueba {
  float: left;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@700&display=swap');
.row {
  background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,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");
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


<div class="row">
  <div class="column1">
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,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">
    <div>
      <div>
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/super-app-hyt/"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGIAAAA7CAYAAACAJF8xAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAQlJREFUeNrs1y9OA0EUB+Bh0+AwCBCYCizhBlBFwBBu0itwhDbpCeAASCyLrAI0YhG1TcFs+COYbkqCoYBpdibfl2zeZnfEy/4ybzMhAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD8w1rbG1zvX5/F0l+ypIzX4G14Mks5iE7LQ+jGcvXLst6inqccRNHy/rpfN6d72831g8PUR1ORSqMHu5sxiK1s/xGdVBp9rt/D/s5GeB0ch1n90Tw7Go3D/eQliyCKFJseldViXOWzQ5IMonychodMdkJyo2n+8atpHW5jfYr1YjxpqiBWbB7Ad5cxiJy0ejTFQ9pNLHd/WDp0sl7Nwa635HUVA6sCAAAAAAAAAKn5FGAA3VI9IDNgBgAAAAAASUVORK5CYII="></a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC4Hpuu6HKR7ezaQsLQBIUKw"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGIAAAA7CAYAAACAJF8xAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAQRJREFUeNrs16FKBEEYB/BxWQSLbLIYNFo0Wi541SL6BD6BiKBPoeHEN7h7AMFidC9YLokG84UrBhHLgRgcNBg8ZYOuc8vvB8PA7IQP/gzffiEAAAAAAAAAAACkZSbl4mb3L7fjthtXMeHzU1z9l9PNjiD+NoR23K4qXD1oQhhZwrW1K94rmvAi8tQL3NtYDic7K1/Oz/rDcHh+35gekaVe4NbqwkdDGL++r8+AlhrVrLNpKfR29BzWj6/D8HHcyL+mfFoKXVucD4OjVijmckH8h+5gNPH84u5BEHXqxSB634ShR9SjrHjvxkBXz1D30zxRxmGuDAAAAAAAAAAAAPy6NwEGADm8MWXg+SaaAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"></a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/hytapp/"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGIAAAA7CAYAAACAJF8xAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAQZJREFUeNrs1yFLQ1EUB/DrUGFFHqsLGqyiaVGstmVBwS7sM4h+AbvJL2BUsMxqEvOChtUxLAM1eN5QERmKQfbu/P3gcOFyw4U/97x3UgIAAAAAAAAAAAAA+IW5ql9wsXPRjqXzzZHbqMOnk+1hzkHMVzyEjVjOfzi2FVVE7eccRK3i9yu+bpzurKWrg1Zaby593l7JvTXVcrrs5moj7baaaTh6iXqeqW9EVkHsRQil5UY9FfUFQUzLw2A0Xu/6j17ENF33BuP17Kb/EYog+N+t6fiyN3OvofJzRLiPGr7/xpYBHEUQk7qWyfrvh7pyRmhPminedGOq7mpuAAAAAAAAANl5FWAAAyg34KTTF+oAAAAASUVORK5CYII="></a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a href=" https://instagram.com/hytsuperapp?igshid=YmMyMTA2M2Y="><img src="data:image/png;base64,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"></a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/hytsuperapp?s=21&t=ocxYib8H_NALfEngjz7w7w"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGIAAAA7CAYAAACAJF8xAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAQZJREFUeNrs1yFLBEEYBuBRVLgmVwwGT7AYBC0X7RY5f8CBYBX8EVaLv8BgtBwWBYsYTYr1goYrhuPgwoIa3N2wYDkOPNfd4XlgmB2YMLMv38AXAgAAAAAAAAAAQLXMxXCJpZObTjptT9jS+zjfexLE34ZwmE4XU2xdT8N4reo95iMoiNaM9wnit/a3VvK5214Nd8ftcHawWZuzL8QUxNXRTnjoD8Nas5GPUfIliP/wNkzC7kazWGeh1EVUT9Pl46D4fh6Mf6xVREmWG4tFFVy/vOchjJJPQZQt++mnt/3anj+Gp+l+mpzSoaEroanLuurOhBB6VW7mAAAAAAAAAAAAquhbgAEAEoE5+jjjxs0AAAAASUVORK5CYII="></a>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>

  <div class="column2">
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,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">
  </div>
  <div class="column3">
    <h3>Gaston Garcia</h3>
    <p>CEO-CO FOUNDER</p>
    <hr>
    <p><strong> <a href=""></a> Gaston@hytapp.com</strong></p>
    <p><strong>+1 954 552 7515</strong></p>
  </div>
  <div class="column4">
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,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"
    />

  </div>
  <div class="column5">
    <div> <img src="">
      <iframe width="100" height="100" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Yvqo4YP9vdE" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Tenes varios problemas, pero el principal es que tus imágenes son demasiado grandes. [Ejemplo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2Xmh.png)

Answer (score 1):

Listo, solo corrige el tamaño de tus imágenes ya que como te mencionaron antes tienen mucho espacio, debes dejarlas de máximo 64px y con la imagen que ocupe toda la mesa de trabajo o espacio de la imagen

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul{    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;}
li{    display: inline;
    float: left;
    width: 16px;}

/* Create two equal columns that floats next to each other */

.column1 {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.column2 {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100px;
  /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
}

.column3 {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  font-size: xx-small;
  font-family: Poppins;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100px;
  /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
}

.column4 {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
}

.column5 {
  float: left;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
}

.prueba {
  float: left;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@700&display=swap');
.row {
  background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,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");
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


<div class="row">
  <div class="column1">
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,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">
    
    
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/super-app-hyt/"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGIAAAA7CAYAAACAJF8xAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAQlJREFUeNrs1y9OA0EUB+Bh0+AwCBCYCizhBlBFwBBu0itwhDbpCeAASCyLrAI0YhG1TcFs+COYbkqCoYBpdibfl2zeZnfEy/4ybzMhAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD8w1rbG1zvX5/F0l+ypIzX4G14Mks5iE7LQ+jGcvXLst6inqccRNHy/rpfN6d72831g8PUR1ORSqMHu5sxiK1s/xGdVBp9rt/D/s5GeB0ch1n90Tw7Go3D/eQliyCKFJseldViXOWzQ5IMonychodMdkJyo2n+8atpHW5jfYr1YjxpqiBWbB7Ad5cxiJy0ejTFQ9pNLHd/WDp0sl7Nwa635HUVA6sCAAAAAAAAAKn5FGAA3VI9IDNgBgAAAAAASUVORK5CYII="></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC4Hpuu6HKR7ezaQsLQBIUKw"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGIAAAA7CAYAAACAJF8xAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAQRJREFUeNrs16FKBEEYB/BxWQSLbLIYNFo0Wi541SL6BD6BiKBPoeHEN7h7AMFidC9YLokG84UrBhHLgRgcNBg8ZYOuc8vvB8PA7IQP/gzffiEAAAAAAAAAAACkZSbl4mb3L7fjthtXMeHzU1z9l9PNjiD+NoR23K4qXD1oQhhZwrW1K94rmvAi8tQL3NtYDic7K1/Oz/rDcHh+35gekaVe4NbqwkdDGL++r8+AlhrVrLNpKfR29BzWj6/D8HHcyL+mfFoKXVucD4OjVijmckH8h+5gNPH84u5BEHXqxSB634ShR9SjrHjvxkBXz1D30zxRxmGuDAAAAAAAAAAAAPy6NwEGADm8MWXg+SaaAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/hytapp/"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGIAAAA7CAYAAACAJF8xAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAQZJREFUeNrs1yFLQ1EUB/DrUGFFHqsLGqyiaVGstmVBwS7sM4h+AbvJL2BUsMxqEvOChtUxLAM1eN5QERmKQfbu/P3gcOFyw4U/97x3UgIAAAAAAAAAAAAA+IW5ql9wsXPRjqXzzZHbqMOnk+1hzkHMVzyEjVjOfzi2FVVE7eccRK3i9yu+bpzurKWrg1Zaby593l7JvTXVcrrs5moj7baaaTh6iXqeqW9EVkHsRQil5UY9FfUFQUzLw2A0Xu/6j17ENF33BuP17Kb/EYog+N+t6fiyN3OvofJzRLiPGr7/xpYBHEUQk7qWyfrvh7pyRmhPminedGOq7mpuAAAAAAAAANl5FWAAAyg34KTTF+oAAAAASUVORK5CYII="></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href=" https://instagram.com/hytsuperapp?igshid=YmMyMTA2M2Y="><img src="data:image/png;base64,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"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/hytsuperapp?s=21&t=ocxYib8H_NALfEngjz7w7w"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGIAAAA7CAYAAACAJF8xAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAQZJREFUeNrs1yFLBEEYBuBRVLgmVwwGT7AYBC0X7RY5f8CBYBX8EVaLv8BgtBwWBYsYTYr1goYrhuPgwoIa3N2wYDkOPNfd4XlgmB2YMLMv38AXAgAAAAAAAAAAQLXMxXCJpZObTjptT9jS+zjfexLE34ZwmE4XU2xdT8N4reo95iMoiNaM9wnit/a3VvK5214Nd8ftcHawWZuzL8QUxNXRTnjoD8Nas5GPUfIliP/wNkzC7kazWGeh1EVUT9Pl46D4fh6Mf6xVREmWG4tFFVy/vOchjJJPQZQt++mnt/3anj+Gp+l+mpzSoaEroanLuurOhBB6VW7mAAAAAAAAAAAAquhbgAEAEoE5+jjjxs0AAAAASUVORK5CYII="></a>
      </li>
    </ul>


  </div>

  <div class="column2">
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,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">
  </div>
  <div class="column3">
    <h3>Gaston Garcia</h3>
    <p>CEO-CO FOUNDER</p>
    <hr>
    <p><strong> <a href=""></a> Gaston@hytapp.com</strong></p>
    <p><strong>+1 954 552 7515</strong></p>
  </div>
  <div class="column4">
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,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"
    />

  </div>
  <div class="column5">
    <div> <img src="">
      <iframe width="100" height="100" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Yvqo4YP9vdE" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```